# How to modify a 2-D array with variable sizes by a function in c?

Tags: arrays, pointers

Is it possible to pass a 2-D array with variable row and column to a function and modify it?
Based on the resources on line I got, [How to pass a 2D array as a parameter in C](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pass-2d-array-parameter-c/) and [Passing 2-D Array to a Function in C](https://overiq.com/c-programming-101/passing-2-d-array-to-a-function-in-c/), seemingly I need a fixed row and column array.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I just got a possible solution for the question.
Based on "[passing 2d array as parameter to function in c” Code Answer](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/c/passing+2d+array+as+parameter+to+function+in+c)", the function is defined as `void fun(int *arr, int m, int n)`.
But if there are any other sophisticated answers, please share with me.
Thanks,